# Targeting different iPad models and iOS versions due to results in UI scaling is different?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, ios8

I will launch my App for the first time targeting iPads (universal). My problem is I came across some inequalities in how the UI scales at different iOS-versions and iPad models. This is the list of different models form the iPad simulator I tested it against:

iPad 2 7.0

iPad 2 7.1

iPad 2 8.1

iPad Air 7.0

iPad Air 7.1

iPad Air 8.1 (scales perfectly)

iPad Retina 7.0

iPad Retina 7.1

iPad Retina 8.1 (scales perfectly)

*Some examples and results can be seen in this Picture below in the inequalities how the tabBar scales and my UISlider in the UI between models/versions:*

[image]

My questions are.

**1**.How come my tabBar background picture is so messed up in example iPad 2 iOS 7.0 and not iPad Air 8.1 ? (Is it different dimensions I need to consider while using a bacground picture?)

**2**.Can I possibly target different models / versions of iPads and fix my UI problems like you do with macros for iPhone6 / iPhone6P ? And then how?

**3**.How come the interface tabBar background picture scales differently in for example **iPad Air 7.0** and **iPad Air 7.1**?. These are the same iPad models with the only inequalities in different iOS versions?

All help is appreciated / Regards

Comment: I've never seen any difference at all for an iPad models. The design is that all iPad models have screens that are 1024x768 **points**, with Retina iPad screens having a scale factor of 2pts:1px. Can you show the code or describe the XIB for how you create the images on the screen? For iPad 2 models, are you making sure to provide "@1x" images or constraining the image's display frame?